# Что за оборот "закон-законом"?

Tags: фразеология

Если посмотреть на цитату:

> Тут же оговаривался он, что всякая истина конкретна и потому закон-законом, но надо понимать ещё и конкретный момент, обстановку — то, что требуется в данную минуту.

То что здесь *закон-законом* — ошибочное употребление дефиса или же есть такое слово?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это словосочетание "закон законом" с раздельным написанием. Имеется в виду: закон пусть будет законом, а далее следует какое-либо сопоставление. Иногда используется авторское тире, но не дефис.

Похожие примеры: чин чином, честь честью, дурак дураком. Такие выражения следует отличать от наречий с повтором основ и дефисным написанием: давным-давно, полным-полно, которые используются для эмоциональной выразительности.

Примеры:

Святость святостью, а закон законом! ― сказал он. Клава Ивановна стояла на своем: закон ― законом, а обязательство в письменной форме ― это в письменной форме, мертвым грузом лежать не будет.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, что дефис не нужен, как и в случае имеющегося в словаре Даля "смех смехом". Это устойчивое выражение несёт такой сокращённый смысл: "никто не спорит, что и здесь **закон** остаётся **законом**, но...". Чисто формально, если бы сокращение состояло в пропуске одного очевидного слова, можно было бы заместить его тире, но не дефисом.